# How to search keywords from MongoDB using NodeJS express framework (Error: MongoDB schema.index is not a function)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to search the keywords in the MongoDB document using NodeJS express framework. I am using search text for mongoose but getting "error": "Minutes.index is not a function"

Schema:

```
const MinutesSchema = new Schema({  
            
    minute_id :{
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },

    minute_type :{ 
        type: String, 
        default: "",
    },
        
    description :{ 
        type: String, 
        default: ""
    },
  
}, {collection:"pm_meeting_minutes"});

const Minutes = mongoose.model('pm_meeting_minutes', MinutesSchema);

exports.Minutes = Minutes;
```

//This is what I have tried in my model function

```
exports.getSearch = () => {
 
   Minutes.index({ minute_type: "text"});
   
   return Minutes.find( { $text: { $search: "Issue" } } )

}
```

//The error I keep on getting is

"error": "Minutes.index is not a function"

//Expected output

To get all the documents that contain minute_type="Issue" from MongoDB

Kindly help me to debug the code.

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
const Minutes = mongoose.model('pm_meeting_minutes', MinutesSchema);
```

to

```
exports.Minutes = mongoose.model('pm_meeting_minutes', MinutesSchema);
```

and remove exports at end line